# Mean value inequality geometrical interpretaion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The mean value inequality theorem

Let U be an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that  $K \ge 0$ and that, $a,b \in U$ 
with $b>a$. If $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable with $f'(t) \le K$ for all $t \in U$,
then $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \le K$

What is the best visual interpretation of the above result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider mechanical interpretation. $f'(t)\leq K$ means that instantaneous velocity at some interval $I$ can reach maximum K value. $\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\leq K$ means that then average velocity at any subinterval of $I$ can't be bigger than K.

Comment: Awesome interpretation. Thanks a lot